# Could someone help explain the priority of log level configuration of ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, logging, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I am now handling the logs in my ASP.NET Core project (based on .NET 6), and I need to reduce some logs from Microsoft.AspNetCore library.
I configured log setting in appsettings.json as below:

```
"Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics": "Information", // Required
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning", // Avoid any logs from other classes under this namesapce
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
```

Could someone help me to check whether this setting can achieve my requirement?
Does the log level of Microsoft.AspNetCore will override the setting of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does the log level of Microsoft.AspNetCore will override the setting of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics?

No, as per [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/logging?tabs=command-line#configure-logging) the most specific category is applied.

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

> In the preceding JSON:

> - The `"Default"`, `"Microsoft"`, and `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"` log level categories are specified.
> - The `"Default"` value is applied to all categories that aren't otherwise specified, effectively making all default values for all categories `"Information"`. You can override this behavior by specifying a value for a category.
> - The `"Microsoft"` category applies to all categories that start with `"Microsoft"`.
> - The `"Microsoft"` category logs at a log level of `Warning` and higher.
> - **The `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"` category is more specific than the `"Microsoft"` category, so the `"Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime"` category logs at log level `"Information"` and higher.**
> - A specific log provider is not specified, so `LogLevel` applies to all the enabled logging providers except for the Windows EventLog.